# Applying augroup to more than one extension

Tags: vim

I have the following `augroup` for binary files in my `.vimrc':

```
augroup Binary
au!
au BufReadPre *.bin let &bin=1
au BufReadPost *.bin if &bin | %!xxd
au BufReadPost *.bin set ft=xxd | endif
au BufWritePre *.bin if &bin | %!xxd -r
au BufWritePre *.bin endif
au BufWritePost *.bin if &bin | %!xxd
au BufWritePost *.bin set nomod | endif
augroup END
```

How can I make it work with file extensions other than `.bin` (without repeating all the lines quoted above)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto commands take comma separated lists for the autocommand pattern

So if you wanted to add the file extension `*.xxx` to the list the autocommands in your group it would look like

```
augroup Binary
au!
au BufReadPre *.bin,*.xxx let &bin=1
au BufReadPost *.bin,*.xxx if &bin | %!xxd
au BufReadPost *.bin,*.xxx set ft=xxd | endif
au BufWritePre *.bin,*.xxx if &bin | %!xxd -r
au BufWritePre *.bin,*.xxx endif
au BufWritePost *.bin,*.xxx if &bin | %!xxd
au BufWritePost *.bin,*.xxx set nomod | endif
augroup END
```

Take a look at `:h autocommand-pattern`